# Have something do something

Tags: causative-have, causative-get

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive/have-something-done)

> We use the pattern *have + object + infinitive without to* when we talk
>   about instructing **someone** to do something. We use it to
>   emphasise who performed the action.

My question is can the object be **something** instead of **someone**? For example

> I have GCC compile my C programs.

Comment: Optional reading [have somebody do something vs. have somebody doing something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208233/have-somebody-do-something-vs-have-somebody-doing-something)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example works.  But you can only do that in a limited number of situations.

You would not say "I have the vacuum clean my carpets", or "I have the oven cook some potatoes".

Comment: I guess it works only with somethings that are living or if someone is a something, Artificial intelligence perhaps?

Comment: An organization with some agency: "I have the security company sweep my office for bugs", "I have the district court issue an injunction".  A device that's a proxy for a person: "I have the answering machine take all my calls"

Answer (score 1):

I do not like your version. I would say either of these two:

"I have GCC to compile my C programs." OK

"I use GCC to compile my C programs." Better

There is no sense in which you instruct GCC to do something. You command a computer to execute the GCC compiler along with parameters that specify where the program source is to be found.

Comment: This answer is misleading. *I have GCC compile my programs* and *I have GCC to compile my programs* are both valid, and mean entirely different things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible, yet it's this construction that means "to give someone the responsibility to do something." [have + person + verb]

But these examples sound right to me:

- Can I have the robot do the cleaning of the floor today?
- I have my laptop bot remind of my daily tasks.